# why is clojure thread last (->>) a macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

The only benefit I can see is that it means that one avoids calls to `partial`.

```
(defn foldl [f acc xs]
  (loop [acc acc
         xs xs]
    (if (empty? xs)
      acc
      (recur (f (first xs) acc) (rest xs)))))

(defn $ [f x] (f x))

(defn thread-last [x & rest]
  (foldl $ x rest))
```

which gives:

```
(thread-last (range 10)
             (partial map inc)
             (partial filter odd?)
             (partial reduce +)) => 25

(->> (range 10)
     (map inc)
     (filter odd?)
     (reduce +)) => 25
```

Are there any cases when a functional / explicit version would fail?

Comment: Are you asking for cases where sticking `partial` at the beginning of each form wouldn't work, or are you asking for *useful* such cases?

Comment: the first, as in which cases couldn't one use partial (or a lambda for argument placement).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, note that your `foldl` is just `reduce`. Our language isn't *that* much poorer than Haskell!

Second, not all forms are function calls, and `->>` can rewrite all forms. For example, you could use `->>` to implement something a bit like Haskell's `where` clauses:

```
(defn mapcat' [f xs]
  (->> (apply concat mapped)
       (let [mapped (map f xs)])))
```

Not really a style that is popular with Clojure programmers, but it serves as an example of something `->>` can do that `partial` can't.

Comment: No negative connotations were intended :) I'm using clojure in production these days, so it more about dispelling any 'magic'. I wrote foldl as I was playing around with a foldl-while and other constructs.